# In Geb, how to assign a list of inputs to a list of HTML input entities

Tags: groovy, spock, geb

I have a question, I’ve got a CSS selector that returns back a list of input objects (all text inputs) and I’d like to easily set the values to them.

I’d like to be able to do something like this:  (assume that addressTextFields is a collection of only html text inputs)

// currently this assigns each field as the String "["New","Belgium",".........

`addressTextFields = ["New", "Belgium", "500 Linden Street", "Suite 200", "Fort Collins", "98026", "970-111-2222"]`

or

// Fails to compile since the cast between ArrayList and WebElement isn't possible...though, I like the syntax :-)

`addressTextFields << ["New", "Belgium", "500 Linden Street", "Suite 200", "Fort Collins", "98026", "970-111-2222"].each { it -> it }`

any thoughts on how to assign values to the text field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the = and << operator on the list of input fields instead of for a single input field
you are trying to set the list of addressTextFields to ["New", "Belgium", …] or adding the different elements of ["New", "Belgium", … ] to the list of addressTextFields.

What you actually want to do is to assign each elemnt as a value to a text field:

```
def values = ["New", "belgium", … ]
addressTextFields.eachWithIndex { input, i -> input = values[i] }
```

If you work with modules or pages you can easily create a method on the module or page level that takes a list of Strings as input and assigns each value to the corresponding text input field.

```
// Module or page method
def setTextFieldValues(List values) {
   addressTextFields.eachWithIndex { input, i -> input = values[i] }
}

// From within test
setTextFieldValues(["New", "Belgium", … ])
```

Comment: For the record, I ended up needing to use the left shift (<<) to fill the value inside of the closure.  I was close to the syntax, but I'm still pretty new to Groovy :)

`// Module or page method
def setTextFieldValues(List values) {
   addressTextFields.eachWithIndex { input, i -> input << values[i] }
}

// From within test
setTextFieldValues(["New", "Belgium", … ])

`